# How to loop year & month condition together to filter correctly via AJAX?

Tags: filters

So I've been trying to create a filter function via AJAX that can help view the latest postings of a custom type post.

So far I'm able to work out the AJAX part, and even the Year filter, however i am stuck where I need to give a scenario where when the page first loads, to load all months of the year if there's no specific month, and when there IS a specific month, to only load those postings in that month of that same year.

Let me show you the codes:

```
        //Search Media According to Year Select
        if(isset($_GET['year_select'])) {
            $temp = sanitize_text_field(($_GET['year_select']));
            $year_select = intval($temp);
        } else {
            $year_select = $latest_year;
        }

        $date_query_array = array(
            'year' => $year_select
        );

        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );

        $year_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'media',
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'meta_query' => $query_array,
            'date_query' => $date_query_array,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $specific_year = new WP_Query($year_args);
        //End Searching
```

And here's the loop:

```
                    if($specific_year->have_posts()) {
                        while($specific_year->have_posts()) {
                            $specific_year->the_post();

                            $title = get_the_title();
                            $media_news_location = get_field('media_news_location');

                ?>
                    <tr class="news-events-tablerow">
                        <td class="news-events"><h4><?php echo get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></h4></td>
                        <td class="news-events">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3></a>
                            <b><?php echo $media_news_location?></b> - <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 30, '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read more</a>')?>
```

From what I understand, I need a way to modify the loop such that
- on the first visit & the variable month is not set, to show all postings of that month of the latest year
- after setting the filter for a specific month, to only show postings of that month only, of that year.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
                    if($specific_year->have_posts()) {
                        while($specific_year->have_posts()) {
                            $specific_year->the_post();

                            $title = get_the_title();
                            $media_news_location = get_field('media_news_location');


                            require get_template_directory().'/inc/process_news_title.php';
                ?>
                    <tr class="news-events-tablerow">
                        <td class="news-events"><h4><?php echo get_the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></h4></td>
                        <td class="news-events">
                            <?php 
                            if ( $item['archived'] ) { 
                                $pdf = get_field('media_'.$post_slug.'pdf');
                                $pdf = $pdf['url'];
                            } else {

                                if($media_type == "event"):
                                    $event = get_field('media_event_pdf');
                                    $pdf = $event['url'];
                                else:
                                    $pdf = get_field('media_archived_link');
                                endif;


                            }
                            ?>
                                <!-- <a href="<?php echo $pdf ?>" target="_blank"> -->
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3></a>
                                    <b><?php echo $media_news_location?></b> - <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 30, '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read more</a>')?>
                                        <img src=""><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
                                </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </table>
                <div class="pub-pagination">
                    <?php echo paginate_links(array(
                        'total' => $specific_year->max_num_pages
                    )); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Something's wrong!

Comment: Use the `month_select` you get from your url in your `$date_query_array` as the `month`. The docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

Comment: Wow this works. Brilliantly. Many thanks. One last question, how can we set it up so that it displays all post of the year first ie no specific month on first visit?

Comment: Thanks @RMo I figured out how to do it - by defining -1 for an initial selection! One final thing - if I go to a post that does not have any post, a bug occurs. ie https://lbs.com.my/press-releases/?month_select=8. Any tips on this one?

Comment: Add an `else` to `if($specific_year->have_posts()) {}` and echo a no posts found message (or whatever you want).

Comment: Can you have a look at the edited addition please @RMo , i tried putting the else clause but gives me errors.